# Sqoop list-databases requires --connection-manager

Tags: jdbc, sqoop, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm using Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.4 and I can't use the `list-databases` tool, although `import` is working.

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/  --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username=myusername -P
```

This the result that I get

```
16/08/11 07:44:47 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
16/08/11 07:44:47 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/08/11 07:44:47 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Generic SqlManager.listDatabases() not implemented.
Could not retrieve database list from server
16/08/11 07:44:47 ERROR tool.ListDatabasesTool: manager.listDatabases() returned null
```

The response says that I need to set the `--connection-manager` parameter, which I do not know.

If I will take out the --driver argument, I get exception:

```
16/08/11 07:48:12 ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
        ... 24 more
16/08/11 07:48:12 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:885)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
        ... 24 more
```

What's the value for `--connection-manager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is this:

```
$ sqoop list-databases 
    --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/ 
    --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager
    --username=myusername -P​
```

Same thing goes for `list-tables` tool

```
$ sqoop list-tables 
    --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/mydb
    --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager
    --username=myusername -P
```

I removed the `--driver` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not about the connection manager.

This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port you are trying to connect to. A couple of things could be happening:

1. You have not started your server.
2. Your server is not waiting to accept connections.
3. You are trying to connect to the wrong port number.